# Test coverage for a wrapper class

Tags: apex, unit-test

I've got the following wrapper class that has no constructor, methods, getters or setters:

```
public class Vehicle 
{
    public class RegistrationInfo {
        public String registrationId;
        public String registrationEndDate;
        public Plate plate;
        public ModelData vehicleModel;
    }

    public class Manufacturer {
        public String code;
        public String description;
    }

    public class Plate {
        public String plateNumber;
        public String plateType;
    }

    public class ModelData {
        public Manufacturer manufacturer;
        public Manufacturer model;
        public Manufacturer bodyShape;
    }

    public class Vehicles 
    {
        public RegistrationInfo registrationInfo;
    }
}
```

Creating instances of each class separately doesn't seem to cover it, so I guess the test coverage is evaluated only for methods (constructors, getters/setters)?

A couple of questions:

1. Does this particular class count towards the overall coverage (reduces it) inside the org?
2. There isn't really anything to be tested here, so if the answer of the above is yes then is there a way to cover this class without having to add a constructor or getter/setter methods for the variables?

Comment: For 2) because for 1) I am not sure, I can only say I think it does. Every class has default empty constructor like Class(), and for the fields just set the values to appropriate types

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if this helps. There is an [help article](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000213804&language=en_US) on this I guess, which may help you. Code coverage counting has changed a bit with Spring 15, and class/variable delcarations are **not** included in the required coverage count: therefore this wrapper class does not need to be covered.

Comment: That makes sense, though it doesn't say anything about declaring classes. I assume the same logic applies but I guess that needs to be tested!

Comment: Thanks for the link. I was wondering why the system wasn't working the way I remembered it.

Comment: I've created a class with 500 variables and it didn't affect the overall coverage, even though that class had 0% coverage. So variable and class declaration as well does not count!

Answer (score 2):

When I put this class in my org, I got that it has 0/1 for lines of test coverage:

[image]

It looks like Salesforce probably added that one to avoid a division by zero. When I tried adding a constructor to one of the classes and ran a test I got 1/1 for test coverage with the constructor highlighted as the one line.

[image]

This is just the default constructor, so explicitly declaring it won't actually change anything with the way your code functions, and you'll get 100% test coverage.